# Genericons work on testserver but not on real server

Tags: fonts

the title say it all on my online-test-server genericons work -> http://panorama-publishing.de/s/

yet when copying the site over to the actual server they don't work -> http://contected.com/

Thats all I can tell you - it's literally 1:1 the same site...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kaiser i check the odd one, on the image tag the string "_iPhone" is added with all images before the extension(.PNG) , try To Remove- It Will be solved,

Ex: "http://www.contected.com/pics/me_de_iPhone.PNG" - Doesnot available.
"http://www.contected.com/pics/me_de.PNG" - available.

Comment: No i wasnt talking abuot the pictures, they are working ont he actual page (just not on the test server since we changed the names) i am talking about the "genericons" icons like the arrow pointing down to the next page